# How to run and forget a command in php on windows

Tags: php, windows, exec, background-process, putty

What I'm trying to do is to run on Windows a command, that lauches putty.exe with specyfic parameters, that will start a connection and run some commands, that are in txt file on a specified in a putty session other server. I just had to run some scripts from the other server on linux, while this main script will run on windows server.

It looks a like that:

```
$putty_exe_path = 'C:\\putty\\putty.exe';
$linux_command_txt_file_path = 'C:\\putty\\commands_to_run_on_linux.txt';
$putty_session_name = 'puttysessionname';
$linux_user = 'root'; 
$linux_password = 'password';

$cmd = "\"\"".$putty_exe_path."\" -load ".$putty_session_name." -l ".$linux_user." -pw ".$linux_password." -m \"".$linux_command_txt_file_path."\"\"";             

shell_exec($cmd);
```

And it works, but there is a problem when script on the linux, that I run using this way is running for a long time because my script is wating for output. I would like to run that command with exec()/shell_exec() or somehow on windows server and exit. I don't need the output. I need to fire and forget. I was looking for a solution but all I found is this:

```
> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

but it doesn't work on windows I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute a console command in windows and don't await for its output you redirect the output to **> NUL**

For example , execute this in php :

```
var_dump(system("cmd.exe > NUL"));// will output inmediately string(0)""
var_dump(system("cmd.exe"));// will wait for the prompt result and write something like Microsoft Windows bla bla bla ...
```

Aditionally , if you want to  know if this is really doing something, try with :

```
  system("echo SOME TEXT > C:\SOME_FILE.txt"); // tHIS WILL Create a text file in the C disk of windows (but we dont add > NUL because there is already an output path !)
```

Try with it please, read more in :

[more info about](http://www.somacon.com/p395.php)

Comment: Redirecting output to file or to nul didn't work, still script was processing that line untill it was done. But in the "more info about" You sir linked, I found usage of WshShell through new object of COM("WScript.Shell") and using Run() with second param 0 - hidden, and third - false so it does not wait for for the result and script actually continues to work instantly. Thank You!

Comment: Note that, just as in Linux, the `> NUL` will only redirect the regular output, any error output will still be piped back into PHP. To redirect both, regular and error output, you'll have to append `2>&1` — just as in Linux. Your full command would therefore be: `cmd.exe > NUL 2>&1`.

Answer (score 2):

### Not an answer but too long for a comment

It's important to understand what `> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &` is doing.

In Linux/Unix operating systems, /dev/null is an emulated device for "nothing", it discards anything written to it.  It, /dev/null, doesn't exist in Windows.  Research more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device

In linux there are two primary streams of output when running commands, stdout and stderr.  `>/dev/null` redirects stdout to /dev/null, `2>/dev/null` redirects stderr to /dev/null and `&` sends the command to the background.  Now you can use this to look up equivalents in Windows.